# Not able to push after resolving merge conflicts

Tags: git, github

My friend and I had made changes to same branch, he pushed onto it and after sometime I tried to do the same but I got. but I got error saying :

```
error: failed to push some refs to '<repo_name>'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I did a pull from the remote branch and resolved merge conflicts.

But after that when I tried to push to the remote having included changes from both me and my friend it said :

```
Everything up-to-date
```

but my changes are still not reflected in the remote repo. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Did you add & commit again after resolving conflicts ?

Comment: yup! I did man.  @sajibkhan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `local branch` is behind from `remote branch`. So, at first pull the changes of remote then push your changes.

```
$ git fetch
$ git pull origin <branch-name>
$ git push origin HEAD
```

Or, you can use `rebase`. This takes all remote commits then puts your commits at the `top in git log`.

```
$ git pull --rebase
$ git push origin HEAD              # push your local commit(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers said, you may have to specify the remote ref directly, since it looks like your tracking branch must not be set up to push to the correct remote ref.

For example, `git push origin <branchName>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull your friends changes from the branch using

```
git pull origin <branchName>
```

resolve conflicts if any and then try

```
git push origin <branchName>
```